# Credit card payment in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

Is there any credit card scanning and payment method for ios other than the paypal. If so specify the sdk's or link of sdk's please. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Card IO (bought by paypal) were the among the first ones to do it. (I have used it, and is very simple/easy to integrate)

Jumio's Netwsipe sdk is an another option

Comment: ok where will the payment go after scanning the card. Actually i have integrated card io. But dont know how the payment method work exactly. I tested in a simulator and it shows a screen to enter the information but nothing about payment

Comment: what do you mean by "where will the payment go"? cardio wont let you scan card on the simulator.

Comment: ok got that it scans the credit card using device i tested that but how to make payment through credit card possible through card io. Please explain that.

Comment: card.io only reduces the effort of typing credit card number and expiry date. It gives you those numbers on a successful scan. Its up to you to pass those numbers along with cvv name and other details to your server or to some other gateway that you use. If you haven't thought about the gateway you want to use, have a look a braintreepayments.com

Comment: Thank you calvin bhai you were really helpful and supporting bro. Really appreciate it mate thanks